# In java what does this mean? int x = y, z;

Tags: java

Seems like a very silly question, but i am unable to find an answer on this online.

basically what i am confused about is what does this code mean:

```
int x = y , z;
```

Why x has two values, separated by comma?

Comment: Here x is declared as int and initialized to y, where as z is declared as int but not initialized. Comma separates two variable declarations. Please read up on declaration and initialization of variables for a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two separate statements.The first expression x= y is an assignment operation. It assigns the value y to x. The second statement is initialization of z. For this to work, the value y should have been initialized before.

Comment: @HumparDumpar If you found the answer useful. click the "tick" symbol next to my post. Cheers

Comment: (Nitpick.  One statement, two separate declarations.)

Answer (score 4):

It's the same like :

```
int x = y;
int z;
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` doesn't has two values, it has the value `y` has and there is another `int` variable `z`.

Comment: Thanks Guy, I really appreciate it

Comment: @HumparDumpar If `y` was 4 now `x` is 4 and `z` has undefined value.

Comment: @Guy Technically `z` is uninitialized if these are local variables or `0` if they are instance variables.